# Encrypting a password when given cert.cer

Tags: php, encryption

I have acquired a public key from a service provider and i now want to encrypt a password.

I have tried to encrypt this way

```
$publicKey = file_get_contents('cert.cer');
//$plaintext = "Safaricom132!";
$plaintext = "safaricom323!";

openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

echo base64_encode($encrypted);
```

I get this result

```
k97YxoV0uS08ok0n99id8PPp9kfSdebhdHaVroTmGF16hR70+U30xSrsRgIaVvHrzu535oH7Mz2TxkgQktq4TmVnxIhWbwBYDlVfnNoAUaHAW/oOYbF6bRR+vCHvMAI8TrQLaMK8XhVMjHqr27pmoqEyzEYC0sop+rp2T81CcWFlyJDr57GHuSoeka8pHMFSsGGvU7S+K0ZZ7xNQGOUpvT8skDMo3u7RUjbDk466dEtR1SUWfYTwVcrBCAFWI9ElfzFzgrWSr+ECelbU7n4D9dJegt9HvPhI2Nnc2q0V7DvHdwO+lHt7tKlM9xbxCTewiFHWjn9+lCAzwqnorHwN3g==
```

Should i specify the cipher i want to use or is the key i have generated a validly encrypted text?>

Comment: Shouldn't i be using RSA somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *have* specified a cipher. Your certificate undoubtedly contains an RSA public key - so only RSA encryption is possible using this certificate. And you've specified PKCS#1 padding, which determines the encryption scheme used for RSA encryption.

No doubt you've generated a validly encrypted text. However, the only way to be 100% sure is to decrypt said ciphertext with the private key (after base 64 decoding the ciphertext, of course). If that returns your plaintext message - `"safari323!"` - then you know that decryption succeeded.

Note that PKCS#1 is not as secure as it was once thought to be. The current best of breed is OAEP padding or RSA-KEM.